# Error in jelastic php 7.3 regarding zip.so

Tags: php, zip, jelastic

When redeploying or newly deploying a Node with PHP 7.3 (nginx 1.14.2) i get the following error when trying to create a zip-archive in php using zip.so

> php: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so: undefined symbol: zip_file_add

(this is from calling the $zip->addFile() function.

This is a problem across jelastic hosting-providers (tested on two different hosting-providers)

Comment: Was this reported to either/both hosting provider? Can you edit your post with full code to reproduce?

Comment: @Damien-Layershift i reported to one hosting provider yes.
code not working:

`$zip = new ZipArchive();`

`$zip->open('test.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);`

`$zip->addFile($filePath, $localPath);`

workaround that is working for now:
`$zip->addFromString($localPath, file_get_contents($filePath));`

Comment: The reported issue is a registered bug (JE-45110 [PHP 7.3] zip and ioncube modules don't work properly) 
We plan to release the fix on January 3, many thanks for the reporting.

Comment: The fix is already available for all new containers. If you want to get the fix for the CTs that were created before, please contact your service provider.